# How to find a function in PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to add `...` to the end of blog excerpts on a site. Wordpress shows **category.php** as the main source for this page. That page makes a call to **blog-content.php**. Inside the **blog-content.php** file is `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

Does anyone know how I can efficiently locate `the_excerpt()`? It's not being defined in the **functions.php** file.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: In php-eclipse ctrl-click on the function. Other IDEs understanding PHP have similar way.

Comment: Learn to search, first. This could have easily been found via Google or the WordPress website.

Comment: I'm no PHP developer - anything I found on google wasn't dumbed-down enough for me. What's the point of a "supportive" community if they just tell you to google stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [right from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#For_versions_2.9_and_higher_of_WordPress):

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

`the_excerpt()` is a core WordPress function, and won't be defined in your theme files. It's located in [/wp-includes/post-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0), but shouldn't be directly edited. Use a [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) such as the one I've defined above to handle changing things.

Comment: Thanks rnevius. This doesn't make much sense to me (PHP in general), but I'm a step closer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) which is designed to do the kind of things you want.

To use it in your case, this should do the work:

```
ack --php '...'
```

You could do the samething with a combination of find and grep:

```
find . -iname \*php | xargs -i '...'
```